# Organising Data FireBase attach to user node or create independent node?

Tags: firebase

I am creating a social site using Firebase.

Each user possess: workout logs, journals, etc

Do I create branches for these entities where the user is registered on each post or to I attach to the user node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to read out the data later. There are several examples of building social sites on Firebase. http://firefeed.io, for example, organizes data as separate nodes for "sparks", "users". There's another example of how to organize your data in this blog post: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html